# Не срабатывает событие изменения информации в информблоке.

Tags: битрикс

Событие, похоже, не обрабатывается.
Мне нужно при изменении элемента в инфомблоке проверять количество просмотров. Но, похоже, функция обработки событий даже не вызывается.
Файл init.php
Код

```
use Bitrix\Main\EventManager;
$eventManager = EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", array("Test", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate"));
$eventManager->addEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate", array("Test", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate"));
class Test
{
    function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate(&$arFields){
        //\Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(__METHOD__);
        echo $arFields;
    }
    function OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate(&$arFields){
        //\Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(__METHOD__);
        echo $arFields;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

параметр $arFields внутри события - это массив. Лучше использовать для его вывода var_dump. Кроме того по ряду причин вы можете не видеть его вывод (операция выполняется ajax'ом, вывод буферизирован). Если хотите проверить - лучше пишите $arFields в файл:

например так:

```
fwrite(fopen("/path/to/logifle.log","a"),date("c")." ".print_r($arFields,true)."\n")
```